# adding object into a list without declaration

Tags: c#, .net, list, oop

This is the class whose instance I want to insert in the list.

```
public class Abc
{
    public int x = 4;      
}
```

List is made in Program class. How to insert data into list of `Abc` type without using the commented line.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>();
        // abc x = new Abc(); without doing this.

        list.Add(x); //add data to the list of class type abc      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> insert data of a class into a list without creating an object

There is **no** way to to add object **without creating** it although, you can directly add object without **declaration**, using `l.Add(new Abc());` but you have to create object anyway.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Abc> l = new List<Abc>();
        l.Add(new Abc());//add data to the list of class type abc
    }
}
```

You can use [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) as well.

```
List<Abc> l = new List<Abc>({new Abc(), new Abc()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Collection Initializers:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>{ new Abc() };
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid using the new keyword, you'll want to implement IoC, for example with a factory:

```
List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>{ AbcFactory.Get() };

Abc abc = AbcFactory.Get();
List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>{ abc };
```

More:

```
List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>{ new Abc(), new Abc(), new Abc() };

List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>();
list.Add(new Abc());
list.Add(new Abc());
list.Add(new Abc());

Abc abc = new Abc();
List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>{ abc };
```